# How to compare 2 collections in mongodb and find the missing ids

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections in MongoDb and want to compare those and get the difference documents.

for example Collection A has below 5 documents

```
{
    "Number" : "0000A95B"
}
{
    "Number" : "0001385B"
}
{
    "Number" : "0002195B"
}
{
    "Number" : "0002E85B"
}
{
    "Number" : "0002FC5B"
}
```

Collection B has below 3 documents:

```
{
    "Number" : "0000A95B"
}
{
    "Number" : "0001385B"
}
{
    "Number" : "0002195B"
}
```

I need a query to get the documents which are present in A but not in B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could use an aggregation query with a $lookup.

```
db.getCollection("collection_a").aggregate([{
$lookup: {
    from: "collection_b",
    localField: "Number",
    foreignField: "Number",
    as: "b_docs"
}
},{
$match: {
    b_docs: {
        $size: 0
    }
}
}])
```

The first $lookup stage should perform a "join" of sorts on collection_a and collection_b wherein the docs with the matching value of number from b will be added in the b_docs property as an array. If no document is found in collection_b, b_docs should be an empty array, so, just add a $match pipeline to filter the results where the size of the b_docs array is 0.

I have not tested the above query, you might want to try it out.